# Exe file icon change. Icon taken from SHELL32.dll

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to change some exe files icon using my program. 
I've found some info and sample codes in MSDN and websites but i'm still in same place.

I need to extract icon from SHELL32.dll

```
uInt = ExtractIconEx("%SystemRoot%\\system32\\SHELL32.dll" , -63008, &hIcon, NULL, 1);
```

Then update some exe file resources. But here my problems starts.
I don't know how to use HICON returned by ExtractIconEx() function as a parameter of UpdateResource() function.

Here's function code:

```
void ChangeFileIcon(char * file)
{
    HICON hIcon;
    UINT uInt;
    HANDLE hFile;
    LPVOID lpResLock;

    uInt = ExtractIconEx("%SystemRoot%\\system32\\SHELL32.dll" , -63008, &hIcon, NULL, 1);
    printf("%d", uInt);

    lpResLock = LockResource(hIcon); 
    if (lpResLock == NULL){
        printf("LockResource fail ;s\n");
        return ;
    }

    hFile = BeginUpdateResource(file, false);

    if(hFile == NULL){
        printf("hFile == NULL - error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    UpdateResource(hFile, 
        RT_ICON, 
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(1), 
        MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US),
        lpResLock(?),
        SizeofResource(????, ????)););

    EndUpdateResource(hFile, FALSE);
}
```

There is example from MSDN but it didn't help me at all:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Updating_Resources
(in this sample resource from one exe is copied to another)

Thank You for answers,
Bury

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using UpdateResource in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127785/using-updateresource-in-c)

Comment: You'd be much better off doing this with a tool rather than trying to program it. For example, IcoFX would make this trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a HICON in this case, a HICON is a single image in a specific size and color depth, but a "real" icon resource is usually a collection of images (16x16, 32x32 etc)

Don't use ExtractIconEx, switch to LoadLibraryEx (and use one of the load as data file flags) and then use FindResource[Ex] to find the icon resource.