# how to edit a resource file

Tags: c#, file, edit

i am developing a program in C# and i need to use the integrated resource file it is .txt file
i need to save data to it when a button is pressed , lets say the client will press a button 
and then a value of "1" is saved in that txt file which is in the program resource files

Comment: what do you mean by your program's resource files? Do you mean the embedded resources?

Comment: This is not possible.  After a resource is embedded in a DLL or EXE file by the compiler it is no longer modifiable.  This is fundamental to the way executable images work in Windows.

Comment: Why do you want to that?

Comment: A resource is not a "text file". The "text file" you're referring to is a script used at compile time to create and embed resources (which are binary for the most part) into the compiled executable or DLL. IOW, a resource is no more a text file than your executable (written in C#) is text.

Answer (score 0):

You're totally using resources wrong. That being said, you can change resources (add, delete, or modify) using [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648049%28VS.85%29.aspx). <strike>I don't know if it's exposed in .NET or if y</strike> You have to use PInvoke, however, as it's not exposed in .NET. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127785/using-updateresource-in-c) a post that will demonstrate it's use.