# Change the datagridview color specified with column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working on `winform` `C#` `datagirdview` and I would like to change the color of a particular row in my `datagridview`. The row should be changed to red when the value of `columncell` is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [CellFormatting Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx)

```
   private void dataGridView2_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            if (e.Value != null)
            {
                if ((bool)e.Value)
                    dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                else
                    dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

The *value* of `e.value` is base on the `e.ColumnIndex` for more [Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellformattingeventargs.aspx)

Comment: spajce this works, but can you explain how it works please
  if ((bool)e.Value) // what is this?
                    dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;  // and how this works

Comment: thats another issue, you're using `DataTable`? if so, try to modify the `DataRow`

Comment: sir can you help me here also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481330/how-to-change-the-image-in-the-resource-folder-with-the-help-of-open-file-dialog

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if by means of some sort of DataBinding like in WPF you can achieve this, but another way would be to hook to the event that is triggered when a row is created and change the color there.

Try the [RowAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded.aspx) event.

Comment: what to write there? i dont know how to change the color with the columns cell is false. so how to change the full row color? can you help me in detail