# changing row backcolor in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, backcolor

I have Problem with changing rows color in Windows Forms. I did it with Columns and tried the same for Rows but it didn't work. Can someone show me how to do it?

My Code so far:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        abc();
    }

    void abc()
    {
        DataTable hh = new DataTable();
        hh.Columns.Add("1", typeof(string));
        hh.Columns.Add("2", typeof(string));
        hh.Columns.Add("3", typeof(string));

        hh.Rows.Add(new object[] { "a", "b", "c" });
        hh.Rows.Add(new object[] { "a1", "b1", "c1" });
        hh.Rows.Add(new object[] { "a2", "b2", "c2" });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = hh;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows) // trying to change all rows to orange
            dr.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;  // but it doesn't work

        dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange; // doesn't work
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
        dataGridView1.Update();

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige; // this works


    }
}
```

Comment: something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/14508584/1080742

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Datagridview CellPainting event. Just copy this code there.

```
        if (e.RowIndex == -1)
        {
            SolidBrush br= new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.CellBounds);
            e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
                SolidBrush br= new SolidBrush(Color.Orange);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.CellBounds);
                e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);
                e.Handled = true;

        }
```

The if checks if its a Header or not. Use the colors you want.. If you don´t want to paint the header just erase all the code inside the if.

I you want a gradient backcolor tell me..

EDIT:

Here is a code to paint pair rows in one color and impairs in another. You must use the Cellpainting event too..

```
else
        {
            if (e.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
            {
                SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.Gainsboro);

                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.CellBounds);
                e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.CellBounds);
                e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

EDIT 2: Where the cellpainting event is?

[image]

Comment: thanks, I have a stupid question, i can't find Cellpainting event, how can i add it?

Comment: If you created you DataGridView using the form designer, the CellPainting event is in "Show", right above "Mouse". Other nearby events are "CellFormatting", "Cellparsing", etc. You can create it programatically, but as I said, if you created that datagridview using the designer, the use it to create the event.

Comment: @Andres why would you do all painting manually, writing four lines of code, if you need solid color background?

Comment: I was told to do it that way in one of my posts. In my app I used it because I needed to paint a header with a gradient. Does this implementation have performance issues? Or is it almost the same?

Comment: @Andres you know, Linq to Objects is almost the same as manual iteration over collections. Actually manual iteration is faster. Think about why people use Linq

Comment: Sorry, I dont get the point for this example. I´m not an expert in the field, I´m just learning.

Comment: @Andres no problem, I'll explain. It's because of re-use of existing solutions, and writing code on higher level of abstraction. Instead of creating brushes, filling rectangles, etc, you can just reuse already written code: `RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange` also this code abstracts out all painting details, just describing desired result *setting background color of rows*

Comment: To only repaint the background when the grid is initialised (which worked better for me), change... if (e.RowIndex % 2 == 0) ... to ... if (e.State.ToString().Contains("Selected") &&  e.RowIndex % 2 == 0)

Answer (score 3):

Use [DataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsdefaultcellstyle.aspx) to set background color for all rows:

```
dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
```

UPDATE (if you want to paint only some rows) you can use [CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) event:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex > 2) // condition
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
}
```

You can read more about [changing DataGridView styles on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0.aspx).

Comment: thanks, but if i don't want to paint all rows, just a few so how  would i do that?

Comment: What do you mean just a few? what is the condition to know what to paint and which not? Use my code to do that.. I will update my answer to paint a pair row in one color and a impair row in another

Comment: Wouldnt that code have to be in the Cellpainting event lazyberezosky?

Comment: @Andres guys on msdn say that *To customize the styles of cells with particular values, implement a handler for the DataGridViewCellFormatting event.*

Comment: Sure then, Anyways, I was using my answer´s code for painting gradients in my datagridviewrows.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub Coloriage()
    Dim fin As Integer = Gridarticles.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To fin
        If Gridarticles("stock", i).Value < 0 Then
            Gridarticles.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
        ElseIf Gridarticles("stock", i).Value = 0 Then
            Gridarticles.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```