# Datagrid - how to change color of complete row?

Tags: c#, datagrid, colors

i have a windows-form that contains a datagrid.
Currently i have the event "dataGrid_CellFormatting" that checks if the content of a cell contains the word FAIL and the changes the color of this cell to red. This works.
What do i have to change that the complete row is changed to red and only the cell?

Thx

```
    private void dataGrid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("cResult"))
        {
            if ((String)e.Value == "FAIL")
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing row backcolor in datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522930/changing-row-backcolor-in-datagridview)

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you are not just changing all the cells in the row?

```
private void dataGrid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("cResult"))
    {
        if ((String)e.Value == "FAIL")
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells)
            {
                cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```