# how to change the icon of an application

Tags: c#, icons

I want to modify the icon of an external application programmatically. I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127785/using-updateresource-in-c) article but have not resolved, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

WinApi provides function [`UpdateResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which allows you to change any resource of in PE file.

This problem was already solved on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127785/using-updateresource-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

Project properties -> Application -> Icon and manifest, assuming Visual Studio 10

Comment: thanks,but it is not want i want,I'm trying to change the icon of external executable programmatically. I've googled and found much information about this problem using C++. Basically, I need to use BeginUpdateResource, UpdateResource and EndUpdateResource. The problem is - I don't know what to pass to UpdateResource in C#.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with Icon section defined in the end of screen

[image]

Comment: It's not for changing the icon at runtime.